Static React app served on Caddy isn't making fetch request to Django
I have a React app on my server with a Django api and serving the static React build using Caddy. I chose to serve my react app as SPA and keep the Django api separately instead of serving the static react files through Django. Currently there are no fetch requests being made to the Django server.
My Caddy config:
www.example.com:443 {
  root * /srv/www/homepage/build
  try_files {path} /index.html
  reverse_proxy /api/* 127.0.0.1:8000
}

The relevant lines of my settings.py:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'https://www.sinanokman.com',]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "Content-Type",
    "Authorization",
)

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

And the fetch request:
async function getRecipes (query) {
    query = (query) ? query : "";
    const res = await fetch(`/api/recipes?q=${query}`);
    const data = res.json();
    return data;
}

I have tested the django server using curl and I can see a get request in my django log. However when i open my website on my browser I don't see any requests being made to Django. My fetch request gets transformed into https://www.example.com/api/recipes?q=, which yields no results. Everything works in development and ask you should be able to tell I am new to this and can't figure out how to solve this issue.
